# Can't find extension

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode9

I have inserted my extension files to XCode 9 project.
And I have made "New Group with folder" to group extensions.
but, I can't use that extensions in other group(that's real folder).
If I make group (extensions group) with "New Group without folder", I can use extensions in other group.

But, It's good "New Group with folder" rather than "New Group without folder" because I can separate many files Finder too.

What is needed to use extensions in other group?

Answer (score 0):

1. Select your folder/file in Xcode.
2. Open the Identity and Type inspector.
3. Click "Location" drop-down menu.
4. Select "Absolute Path".

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I have followed your solution but in that case can't use extension inside same group too.
Maybe XCode has 2 different group type.

Comment: Sorry. I've updated my answer now. Should be absolute path. There is a more comprehensive answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41699971/xcode-8-2-1-cannot-add-folder-reference)

Comment: That doesn't work for me.
When I change folder Location to "Absolute Path", extension can't be used in same folder inside too.
and when I change the folder location to "Absolute Path", individual files location is still "Relative to group".
Do I have to change individual files locaiton property too ?
if it's true, maybe I have to use "group without folder" I think.

Comment: Yes you'll have to change the path for the individual files as well. I normally use group without folder myself though.